# CSS and JS don't load in mobile after configuring Fastly CDN in Magento 2.x Enterprise Cloud Edition

Tags: magento-2.1, magento2-enterprise

I am working on a **Magento 2.x Enterprise Cloud Edition** project and have configured **Fastly CDN** after moving to the staging environment.

The website opens fine on desktop, but when I checked in mobile, I found that both CSS and JS don't load.

Has anyone faced the similar issue?

Can anyone guide me how to solve it?

Thanks in advance